# How to show the IPv4 and IPv6 adress from the website visitor

Tags: php, apache, ipv6, ipv4

i have a litle php website which shows the ip adress from the visitor. I have seen other sites which can show the IPv4 and the IPv6 Adress. When i visit my page i only see the IPv6 adress. When i visit for example wieistmeineip.de i see both (even without javascript). I think they let the client make a second request on a server that only excepts IPv4. Have any one a solution for that? What would be the easiest way to only except IPv4 on an second server and to get both request from the client?

Thanks a lot

Frank

Comment: One thing I have seen happen is that a web page will have an element, such as a one pixel image, that must be loaded from a particular IP (IPv4 or IPv6) that is different than the IP used to load the page. That will give the address of the other IP used on the browser host.

Comment: With modrewrite  in .htaccess I can check the ipv6 variable. And i could use header in php to redirect. I think with the image Option, i have to use java script. I think i realy have to use two server. One which only accept ipv4 and one for the ipv6 and bring them together with two redirects. But that's a lot of effort. Could it be solved with sockets?

Comment: Sockets would require you to have the IPv6 address already. You cannot create an IPv4-to-IPv6 socket because IPv4 and IPv6 are completely separate, incompatible protocols. Also, I do not see where it would require two separate servers if the one server is dual-stacked. Use the IPv6 address in the image anchor, instead of using a DNS name. Do the same thing for and IPv4 image for browsers that connect with IPv6.